# Count city and State from 2 different tables

Tags: sql

I need to count the number of cities occurrences on 2 different tables. One Table is the Supplier  table which has supplier_id, City and State. The second table is consumer with consumer id , City and State. My query needs to return the State, City number of supplier cities and number of consumer cities where the names match.

I have tried a couple different things like intersect and union all but cant get it My latest is below but it is Not sure what I am doing wrong

```
   SELECT S.State
   ,C.City
  ,count(S.City) as Number_Of_Suppliers
  ,count(C.City)  as Number_Of_Consumers
  from dbo.Tb_Supplier S                     
  left outer Join dbo.Tb_Consumer C
On  S.STATE = C.STATE
AND S.City = C.City
 group by S.state
  ,C.City
```

Comment: this is just a little too complex to try and bridge the gaps without more information. what type of database are you using (mysql, oracle, sql server)? more importantly, if you could provide the scripts that would create your two tables and load them with data it would be a lot easier to come up with a solution. If I had this I would be able to get you an answer, but it's just too hard to try and mock up your situation without this data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select state, city, sum(supplier)
        sum(supplier) as Number_Of_Suppliers,
        sum(consumer) as Number_Of_Consumers
from ((select state, city, 1 as supplier, 0 as consumer
       from dbo.Tb_Supplier s
      ) union all                    
      (select state, city, 0 as supplier, 1 as consumer
       from dbo.Tb_Consumer c
      )
     ) sc
group by state, city
```